# How to create mipmap for Unity3d textures loaded with www?

Tags: textures, unity

When I load a texture using the code below:

```
WWW www = new WWW(textureName);     

yield return www;

renderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Diffuse"));

Texture tex = www.texture;
tex.filterMode = FilterMode.Trilinear;

renderer.material.mainTexture =tex;
```

The texture does not come with mipmaps, how can I tell unity to generate the mipmaps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply [create a new texture](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.Texture2D.html) using the width/height information from the WWW's texture, and pass `true` to the `mipmap` parameter of the constructor. Then you can use the GetPixels and SetPixels methods to copy the data over (the texture returned from the WWW object is read-only so you probably can't modify it directly).

See also:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/2814/how-do-i-generate-mipmaps-at-runtime