# Mip Maps on 2D Sprite causing black line above. Why is this?

Tags: unity, textures, sprites, mipmaps

I am new to Unity. I'm trying it out and using [Futile](http://struct.ca/futile/) for a code-first approach, but still importing textures using the Unity system.

The problem I'm having is that when I use mip maps to scale large sprites down to smaller sizes without jagged edges, I'm getting a black line artefact above said sprites.

[image: Hard to see]

A little hard to see, but they're there. If I turn down the resolution, you can clearly see them:

[image: Easier to see]

These are my texture settings:

[image: Settings]

My question is, why are these black lines here? Is it a mistake I've made? Is it just a common side effect? How can I reduce these? Also, if this is the wrong approach, how can I use smooth sprites in a game with the ability for them to scale up smoothly?

Thanks!

Comment: you are using an atlas, aren't you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many reasons why you may be getting those lines. I wrote a more detailed answer in [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50023/how-can-i-prevent-seams-from-showing-up-on-objects-using-lower-mipmap-levels/50037#50037), but the bottom line is:

> Do not do atlasing and mipmapping at the same time.

For 2D, in general, you don't want/need to do mipmapping. That's useful mostly in 3D where you don't know the size at which your textures will be rendered, but that's usually uncommon in 2D.

If you definitely have a texture that you will aggressively downscale, then don't include it in an atlas.

And I'd also recommend you turn anisotropy off. That's meant to give you better results when you're looking at big textures from extremely sharp angles, which simply doesn't happen if your game is 2D.

Comment: actually a proper padding should allow atlas and mipmap to be used together, am I wrong? +1 btw

Comment: @Heisenbug by adding padding, all you're doing is moving the problem to a lower mip level. If you must have mipmaps *and* atlases, then consider creating them manually, and only down to the level where your smallest object is 1x1 pixel. But in 2D you usually don't downscale textures enough to require mipmapping, so I'd certainly recommend you don't mix atlasing and mipmapping.